# using indexof on query string parameter with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I'm showing hidden divs based on the contents of a query string parameter that's being parsed from another page, using indexof to check if a value is present - then displaying that value's corresponding div.

Query string: `index.html?q1=bag1,bag2,bag3`

```
    var urlParams;
    (window.onpopstate = function () {
        var match,
            pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
            query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        urlParams = {};
        while (match = search.exec(query))
           urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
```

Then using `indexOf` to show divs based on the value:

```
    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag1") >= 0) {
        $(".content1").show();

    } else

    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag2") >= 0) {
        $(".content2").show();

    } else

    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag3") >= 0) {
        $(".content3").show();

    }
```

However, it's only displaying the first div and not the second or third.

I know it'll be a simple solution - bit stuck on it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using your `bag1` etc values as IDs instead of classes to identify the separate content sections.  If a class only identifies one element then you're doing it wrong.

You should then tag *all* of your content elements with the *same* class (e.g. `content`) so that you can `.hide()` on all of them before running `.show` on the ones that you want to remain visible.   As written any elements that are already visible will remain visible when you pop state even if they weren't supposed to be.

Your parameter extracting code is OK, but having got your `q1` value I would just do this:

```
var q1 = urlParams.q1;
if (q1 !== undefined) {
    $('.content').hide();    // show nothing
    q1.split(',').forEach(function(id) {
        $('#' + id).show();
    });
}
```

thereby removing all of the (broken) conditional logic.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the else clauses, as the interpreter will stop after the first if is true. So your code should look like

```
    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag1") >= 0) {
        $(".content1").show();

    }

    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag2") >= 0) {
        $(".content2").show();

    }

    if ((urlParams["q1"]).indexOf("bag3") >= 0) {
        $(".content3").show();

    }
```

Comment: this is technically correct, but I wouldn't accept it in a code review.

Comment: because it needlessly (and unnecessarily) repeats code over and over instead of parameterising the operation.  It's also error prone (as the OP found)